# Return value of printf in C?

Tags: c, printf

My Code:

```c
int main() {
  int x = 10, y;
  y = printf("x = %d\n", x);
  printf("y = %d\n", y);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x = 10
y = 7
```

I know printf returns the number of character when we print string. But why is returning 7 when printing 10. what is the return value of printf when it prints int ?

Possible Duplicate:
[Return value of printf() function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055882/return-value-of-printf-function-in-c)

Comment: Because the string "x = 10\n" contains 7 characters!

Comment: How is it 7? it is 3 right.

Comment: How is it 3?  "x =" has 3 characters.  "x = " has 4, "x = 1" has 5, ...

Comment: @user1762571 I think you are assuming ,scape and new line char are not counted and `10` is single char that is actually two

Comment: @  Grijesh Chauhan - Thank you for this information. i didnt know before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read: [int printf ( const char * format, ... );](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

> On success, the total number of characters written is returned.

for  `x = 10` in your code first printf:

```
printf("x = %d\n", x);
```

prints seven chars `x = 10\n`, and return 7 that is received in `y`:

```
    x = 10\n
    1234567 
     ^ ^  ^- new line char \n
     | |--spaces
```

remember `\n` (new line)is single char, and space is single char.

Comment: *prints 7 chars that is received in `y`* -- I think you should rather write *returns 7( i.e the no. of chars) that is received in `y`*.

Comment: @PHIfounder Thanks! Yet I think `@jh314` explained better than me :)

Comment: yes of course that's why I voted up for him even before you :)

Answer (score 5):

Like you said,  "printf returns the number of character when we print string".

"`x = 10\n`" has 7 chars. (Namely, these: `'x',' ','=',' ','1','0','\n'`).

Thus, y is set to 7.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the string:

```
"x = 10\n"
```

(not including double quotes) is 7 characters. That is what is being stored in *y*. The white spaces and '\n' are also each just 1 character.

Answer (score -1):

"x = %d\n"  Of course there are 7 characters.
Notice there are 2 "space",1 "%" and 1"d", remember "\n" is a whole .
You can try other sentences. such as `z = printf("x = %d,asd\n",x);` or sth. like that.
The answer is 11.
I think such questions can be done by just one more line  codes .