# Strange output from nested printf statemenets

Tags: c, printf, output

Ok, I'm playing a bit with a code, trying do understand some tricks and how does it work, so I don't understand output of this code

```
int i = 8;
printf("%d", printf("%o", i));
```

result of this is 102, I don't know how, I know that 8 in octal system is 10, but what most confuses me is when I put space after `%o` like this

```
printf("%d", printf("%o ", i));
```

now, result is 10 3, what is going on here?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `printf` returns  `int`

Comment: First you print `i`, then you're printing the result of printing `i`. Have you looked at the documentation of `printf` to see what it returns?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, no, printf returns the total number of characters written.

Comment: You get the same result if you do `printf("%d", printf("12"));` versus `printf("%d", printf("123"));`. Octal numbers have nothing to do with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055882/return-value-of-printf-function-in-c

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre where did you get that info that printf returns void?

Comment: @SouravGhosh my mistake. But it still doesn't return the result. Just irrelevant info for what's the OP want to do.

Comment: There are no "tricks" here. Maybe there are incorrect assumptions, and/or opportunities to learn, but that doesn't make the code "tricky".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Printf prints to standard out, and returns int, the count of printed characters.
So you get:

10 3

which is:

10 is the evaluated inner printf that prints octal 8.

and 3, the evaluated outer printf that prints the "return" value of the inner printf = 3 printed chars.

Answer (score 5):

The outer `printf()` will print the return value of the inner `printf()`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1,

> The `fprintf` function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value
>   if an output or encoding error occurred.

So, in the first case,

```
 printf("%d", printf("%o", i));
```

the inner `printf()` prints `10`, i.e., two characters, which is the return value of the call and the outer `printf()` prints that. Output of two adjacent print statements appear as `102`.

Similarly, when you put a space after in the format specifier of the inner `printf()`, it prints (and returns) 3, so after the `10 <space>`, `3` is printed.

Comment: aah, I see, so those numbers after 10 are actually numbers of printed characters, even space counts, I understand now, thank you all for fast answers

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 8;
printf("%d", printf("%o", i));
```

`printf` returns the amount of characters it printed, which is 2 for printing `10` before. The order of evaluation means you'll get `102` as output. Or rather `10` and then `2` without a newline or space in between.

In your second example, you get `10` (notice the space) and then `3` (`10` is 3 characters, `{'1','0',' '}`) as the return from `printf`.