# Why does printf() work even without being caught in an integer variable?

Tags: c, printf, return-type

I was wondering if `printf()` in C or C++ programming language returns the **number of characters printed** on screen, then how does

```
printf("%d", 10);
```

work? Why doesn't it show any error(s)?

Rather an integer variable should be used to catch the returned value, as follows:

```
int var = printf("%d", 10);
```

How does `printf()` work internally to resolve this?

Comment: What error are you expecting? You don't have to assign or use the return value of a function.

Comment: You don't mention the programming language, but I don't know of any where you *must* store the return values of functions somewhere. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: If this is your question, yes `int printf()` returns the number of written characters if you are on C/C++, and a negative number on error. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7055895/7477557). To catch errors you can simply do `if( printf(...) < 0 ) manageerror(); `

Note that it does not output the number of items but characters (newline is 1, any byte is 1)

Comment: *"How does `printf()` work internally to resolve this?"* -- `printf()` (or any other function that returns a value) doesn't care what happens with the value it returns. It always returns it and completes; it's up to the calling code to use or ignore the returned value. `C` and other languages inspired from it allow calling a function without using the value it returns.

Comment: If you start out life programming in VBA (where with some syntaxes and functions you *do* need to do something with the return value), this is not immediately obvious. Upped.

Comment: I used to think that it's compulsory to use the returned value of a function. But thankfully, today my misconception is cleared @IgalS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`printf()` does nothing special here. C doesn't require you to do anything with the result of expressions you evaluate.

```
2 + 3;
```

is a perfectly valid statement. (It may generate a warning from your compiler because it doesn't actually do anything, unlike a function call such as `printf()`.)

Let's look at a slight variation of your second version:

```
int var;
var = printf("%d", 10);
```

Here you might think we're "catching" the return value from `printf` in `var`, so there's no result value being left lying around. But `=` is just another operator (like `+` or `&&`) and it returns a value!

```
int x, y, z;
x = (y = (z = 42));  // perfectly valid code
x = y = z = 42;  // same thing; = is right associative
```

`=` returns the value being assigned and this code sets all three variables to `42`.

So if C were to require you to "catch" return values, you couldn't use assignment statements because they also return a value.