# Why does `printf("%c", 5)` print a vertical bar?

Tags: c

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("\t%d\n",printf("MILAN"));
    printf ("\t%c",printf("MILAN"));
}
```

Here is the output

```
$gcc -o main *.c
$main
```

> MILAN    5
>
> MILAN    |

Now the question is

Why printf return | when we are printing characters (formatter as %c) ?

What is the relation between 5 and | here?

Comment: @BoPersson: You sure about that? `'a'`, for example is an `int` type in C, and that can be used in a `printf` with `%c`.

Comment: No. I'm more into C++ where characters are actually characters. So in C printing an int as a character is an exception to "wrong format specifier", ok.

Comment: @BoPersson: Which I dislike intensely.

Comment: The `%c` format specifier expects an `int` argument because of the default argument promotions; if you try to pass _any_ integer type (`char` is an integer type) narrower than `int` as a variadic parameter to a C function, it gets automagically widened to `int` in the process.  So it's not actually possible for `printf` to be pickier.

Comment: @Bathsheba ... and hardly useful to anyone who cares to read the documentation of `printf`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Yeah, let's just close all the C questions as duplicates to the C standard.

Comment: @Bathsheba good idea. Here's a first one

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Nice ;-) Doesn't really explain the behaviour of the control character though?

Comment: I have anti-dupehammered the question and changed the title because I think OP is asking about why 5 becomes `|`, not about the meaning of the return value.

Comment: In questions like this I always want to first ask - what would you *expect* it to print and why?

Comment: Yet no one has managed to answer why the bar is printed. I haven't found any platform/codepage where that would be the case :F

Comment: @AnttiHaapala A thick vertical bar was a placeholder in old windows font set for character codes that are not used for anything in particular.

Answer (score 11):

Your question really boils down to the behaviour of `printf("%c", 5);`.

The actual output is a function of the character *encoding* used by your platform. If it's ASCII (very common) then it will output the *control character* `ENQ`. What you actually get as an output will depend on your command shell, and a vertical bar is not an unreasonable choice.

Comment: $5 on that (a) this is on Windows, and (b) it's *not* the normal `|` but the much thicker "yeah I got nothing" default character in old Windows bitmap fonts.

Answer (score 3):

[`printf` returns the number of characters printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055882/return-value-of-printf-function-in-c). In this case, that number is 5, as you've seen. The second print you're doing tries to typecast that `int` to a `char`, which C lets you do because it's C. On your computer, it shows up as a |. I see it rendered as a blank character. As @Bathsheba says, the integer `5` corresponds to a control character in ASCII, and the rendering for those is system-dependent.

[Here's an ascii table, if you're curious about other numbers](https://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: On my system, running OP's test program with output piped to a hex-dump utility confirms that it prints a character with byte value 5.

Comment: @zwol I should hope so too!